# How do I install runtools for the jupyter notebook?

Tags: installation, ipython, jupyter

I have already copied the runtools directory to .ipython/nbextensions/usability and modified the custom.js file, but it doesn't seem to work. I think the main reason is because I'm working on jupyter. But the installation instructions are not so clear for me.

Could anybody help me?

Comment: With Jupyter, you should be able to run `jupyter nbextension install path/to/runtools`, then `jupyter nbextension enable runtools/main`.

Comment: I did as you told and everything seem to work (thank you very much), it copied the files and so. But when I open the notebook it doesn't have the runtools.

Comment: Open up your browser's JS console - there might be error messages there.

Comment: Where do you download runtools from though?

Comment: Hi, currently you can download them from here https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions